# A Google Play application installed and not installed in the same time

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation

Few days ago I was asked to install [*Mailbox* from Dropbox, Inc.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mailboxapp&hl=en). I went to Google Play and clicked on the `Install` button to request remote installation on my machine. Yesterday, I have realised, that this apps wasn't actually installed. So I went again using PC and saw, that it is installed:

[image]

Since I couldn't find it on my phone, I opened Google Play directly from the device and to my surprise, it turned out, that this application actually isn't installed:

[image]

Is it often to reach such miss-align between mobile and desktop version of Google Play? What can cause this strange situation?

Comment: Sometimes I encounter this case. I can press the "Install" button again from browser, then the app will be really installed after the second time pressing it. As for the cause, I still don't have any idea.